# TensorContract applied twice

Tags: symbolic, tensors, products

I have a very simple question about `TensorContract` command:
I'm declaring

```
$Assumptions = {T \[Element] Arrays[{4, 4, 4, 4}], a \[Element] Arrays[{4, 4}], b \[Element] Arrays[{4, 4}]};
```

so `T` is a rank 4 tensor `a` and `b` are two rank two tensors. Now I want to do the tensor product and contract them this way

```
fc=TensorContract[TensorProduct[T, a, b], {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}}]];
```

this mean tha all indices are contracted, that is `TensorRank[fc]=0`. 
Now I want to do the same operation firstly contractin `T` with `a` and then to contract the result, that is a rank 2 tensor with `b`:

```
c = TensorContract[TensorProduct[T, a], {{1, 5}, {2, 6}}]];
```

infact `TensorRank[c]=2`, now as a rank 2 tensor I would like to contract this wit `b`

```
d = TensorContract[TensorProduct[c, b], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}];
```

this gives a rank 0 tensor, infact `TensorRank[d]=0`. Now if I type

```
d // TensorReduce
```

I get the error message:

```
"Contractions {{1,5},{2,6},{3,5},{4,8}} contain repeated levels.
```

What is happening? How can I do this operation correctly?

Comment: For other readers, or in case it is still helpful to you: I get no error message running this in Mathematica 12.1, and the result for the reduction of d seems to be equal to fc, up to an inconsequential reordering T a b -> a b T.